# Android-PHP , insert into table with other query's data

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

```
$status = 1;
$user_name = aaa;
$mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO l_status (user_id , status) values ('select id from user where username in (''$user_name'')','$status')";
if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE ) {
echo "inserted.";
}
else {
echo "Error" . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

I want to insert id and status in l_status table , i need to pick id from user table.

values are getting inserted but with id = 0 every time. 
in user table id is different for different user.

please help me out here , new to php.

Comment: assign as a string `$user_name = "aaa";` and replace with '$user_name'

Answer (score 1):

```
$user_name = 'aaa';
$mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO chaosgam_ghs.login_status (user_id , status) values ((select user_id from chaosgam_ghs.user_table where username = '$user_name'),'$status')";
```

The code was having 2 errors shown in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Split it up:

```
$mysql_qry = 'SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = "'.$user_name.'"';
while($res = $conn->query($mysql_qry){
$id = $res['id'];
$mysql_qry2 = "INSERT INTO l_status (user_id , status) values ('$id','$status')";
if($conn->query($mysql_qry2) === TRUE ) {
echo "inserted.";
}else {
echo "Error" . $mysql_qry2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Or in one query:

```
$mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO l_status (user_id , status) values ((select id from user where username = '$user_name') ,'$status')";
```

AND PLEASE Take look for your $var = 'test'; -> you must quote them.
Look at your

```
$user_name = 'aaa';
```

Comment: this okay but need `select` query with inside of  `insert` query

Comment: i cant imagine that, but here is what you looking for:

Comment: just imagine. i am looking for single query no split

Comment: $mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO l_status (user_id , status) values ('select id from user where username in (''$user_name'')','$status')";

Comment: Edited my answer above. U see it? You need to take care of braces (SUBQUERY)

Comment: are you test with live ? no imaginary answers

Comment: How could i test it without your Database? I dont know if all columns are right etc. If you get an error provide it, then i see what is wrong. But if you have an user table with the column id -> then my query is working

Comment: i test with dummy data with my environment and i already tried its never worked for me . if we split means its working . original posted by @Hemant Vyas

Comment: INSERT INTO l_status (user_id , status) values ((select id from user where username = '$user_name'),'$status')

Comment: TAKER CARE OF YOUR STRINGS:
NOT WORKING -> $user_name = aaa;

Comment: WORKING -> $user_name = 'aaa'; You must quote your Strings in PHP

Comment: already done with all changes but no success . may be the version problem .

Comment: I dont think so, please provide the mysql error or the php error log. Otherwise it is impossible to help you

Comment: ErrorINSERT INTO I_status (user_id , status) values ('select user_id from user where username in (''aaa'')','1')
Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I see that you took my answer, please upvote it. Thank you and im happy to help you